# How run detox-server on a specific port

Tags: detox

I specified the configuration according to the documentation https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md.

```
 "detox": {
"configurations": {
  "ios.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": ".....",
    "build": ".....",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPad Air 2"
  }
},
"session": {
  "server": "ws://localhost:8099",
  "sessionId": "YourProjectSessionId"
},
"test-runner": "mocha",
"specs": "test/e2e",
"runner-config": "test/e2e/mocha.opts"
```

}

I expect detox to run a detox server on port 8099.
But when starting the tests,
`detox test --loglevel verbose` 
the following errors occur

```
detox ERR! ws onError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8099
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8099
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8099,
  type: 'error',
  target: 
   WebSocket {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: onerror] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _socket: null,
     _ultron: null,
     _closeReceived: false,
     bytesReceived: 0,
     readyState: 3,
     supports: { binary: true },
     extensions: null,
     _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
     _isServer: false,
     url: 'ws://localhost:8099',
     protocolVersion: 13,
     _closeTimer: null,
     _closeCode: 1006 } }
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha test/e2e --opts test/e2e/mocha.opts --configuration ios.sim.debug --loglevel verbose    --grep :android: --invert  
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at runMocha (/Users/sbt-yakimov-vi/Desktop/cib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:114:6)
    at run (/Users/sbt-yakimov-vi/Desktop/cib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:75:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sbt-yakimov-vi/Desktop/cib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:181:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

When running on the generated port, everything works correctly

- detox
- mocha 3.5.0
- macOs 10.13.2

Answer (score 2):

You must run the server yourself with the following code

```
const DetoxServer = require('detox-server')
const URL = require('url').URL;

await new DetoxServer(new URL(config.session.server).port)
```

Json should contain

```
"session": {
  "server": "ws://localhost:8099",
  "sessionId": "cib_app"
}
```